# Android Studio program crashes when user logs in

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am in the midst of creating an Android Studio notes program, and it was working fine, until it suddenly started crashing whenever I tried to log in using Firebase. The thing is, I did not change any code at all so I have no idea how to debug.

I have also tried downloading a different emulator but it didn't work.

I also have a hunch that the error could be to do with Firebase, as nothing happened in between the time it worked and stopped working, except that I deleted all the information (eg. passwords, usernames). However, to my knowledge, nothing should happen as the realtime database will just repopulate whenever I create new users through the app.

**Error message when it crashes**

```
07-24 15:06:45.930 6361-6361/com.example.user.planner E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.user.planner, PID: 6361
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type Model.ListItem
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzb(Unknown Source:262)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zza(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source:10)
        at com.example.user.planner.Notes_Overview$3.onChildAdded(Notes_Overview.java:167)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzecw.zza(Unknown Source:71)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeia.zzbyc(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source:71)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

So I tried debugging based on the error message, which brings me to this particular Java file.

```
public class Notes_Overview extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText task;
private EditText desc;
private Button RedirectToDoButton;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private FloatingActionButton FAB;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private List<ListItem> listItems;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseUser mUser;
private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
private ProgressDialog mProgress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes__overview);

    task = findViewById(R.id.task_title_edittext);
    desc = findViewById(R.id.desc_title_edittext);
    RedirectToDoButton = findViewById(R.id.RedirectCalendarButton);
    FAB = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();


    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(Notes_Overview.this);
    //consider using ProgressBar instead of ProgressDialog
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference().child("To-Dos");
    mDatabaseReference.keepSynced(true);


    FAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startPosting();
        }
    });


    RedirectToDoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Notes_Overview.this, Calendar_Overview.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    listItems = new ArrayList<>();

    //to prevent initialisation of the EditText every time user comes to this activity
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
    //to prevent initialisation of the EditText to shift the layout upwards
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
}


private void startPosting() {

    mProgress.setMessage("Creating note");
    mProgress.show();

    String event = task.getText().toString().trim();
    String description = desc.getText().toString().trim();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(event) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(description)) {

        DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabaseReference.push();

        Map<String, String> dataToSave = new HashMap<>();
        dataToSave.put("event", event);
        dataToSave.put("description", description);


        newPost.setValue(dataToSave);
        Toast.makeText(Notes_Overview.this, "To-Do created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mProgress.dismiss();
    }
}









@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_signout) {
        if (mUser != null && mAuth != null) {
            mAuth.signOut();
            Toast.makeText(Notes_Overview.this, "Signed out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(Notes_Overview.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            ListItem listitem = dataSnapshot.getValue(ListItem.class);
            listItems.add(listitem);
            Collections.reverse(listItems);
            adapter = new MyAdapter(Notes_Overview.this, listItems);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

And the ListItem class is this.

```
package Model;

public class ListItem {
    private String event;
    private String description;

    public ListItem(){

    }

    public ListItem(String event, String description) {
        this.event=event;
        this.description=description;
    }

    public String getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(String event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

I have tried my best to give as much relevant information as possible, but in case more is needed, do let me know.

Comment: I think the problem start at `ListItem listitem = dataSnapshot.getValue(ListItem.class);`. `at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source:10)`

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too, but I have no idea how to even begin debugging. Any thoughts on what might have gone wrong?

Comment: What I understand is the data is saved as a `String` and you try cast to `ListItem`. So what I think you should check is how you put the data in `mDatabaseReference`

Comment: How is `mDatabaseReference` declared? PLease also add your database structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have edited to show the particular java file for that particular activity, as it also contains the database structure. Thanks!

Comment: @codinglearner21 I would like to see the database as JSON export or at least as a printscreen.

Comment: Sry, I'm really new at this, so I don't really understand. But this activity is actually where I declared and defined my Firebase database, if that matters. If it's still unclear, do let me know how I can make it clearer.

Comment: A JSON export or at least as a printscreen fron the Firebase Console.